# Programatically close PreferenceScreen and its PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

Here is the case:

1. From my `MainActivity` I open the `PreferenceActivity` of my app;
2. In `PreferenceActivity` I have two `PreferenceScreens` and also a `MenuItem`with an icon to start another `Activity`  for result. If I enter in any of the `PreferenceScreens` the icon is still visible so I also can start the new `Activity` from the current `PreferenceScreen` that I am in.
3. **Case 1**. If I start the new `Activity` directly from the `PreferenceActivity` without entering in any of its child screen, it
   does its job, returns a result and I am back to the parent
   `PreferenceActivity`. I determine if I am in the
   `PreferenceActivity` and call `finish()` method and return to my
   `MainActivity`- job done!
4. **Case 2.** I enter in a child `PreferenceScreen`, press the `MenuItem` icon, start the new `Activity`, it does its job, returns me a result and I am back to the child screen. I determine If I am in a `PreferenceScreen` and call `finish()`. The child screen is closed but unlike **Case 1**, I am back to my parent `PreferenceActivity`. How to close the parent and return to my `MainActivity`?

Comment: Assuming you use PreferenceFragment under PreferenceActivity, why don't you call getActivity().finish()?

Comment: I am not using PreferenceFragment. :) Just PreferenceActivity with two PreferenceScreens. As i explained, calling finish() in the PreferenceScreen closes the current child but the parent PreferenceActivity remains open. I want to close the parent, too :))

Comment: This is weird. PreferenceScreen is not an Activity, therefore when calling finish(), it should close the parent Activity (PreferenceActivity). Anyway, you can send a broadcast to the parent activity to close it self or return a result and implement onActivityResult in parent Activity, etc.

Comment: Weird but fact - calling finish() in PreferenceScreen closes the screen and the parent remains visible :) Anyway, I figured it out, im going to post the solution, thanks for the comment, i will try the broadcast receiver though, good idea! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.... My `PreferenceActivity` has two `PreferenceScreens`. So to open any of it I use screenPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(). In that listener I just call `PreferenceActivity.this.finish()`. The parent is closed and the child is opened. Already in the `PreferenceScreen` child, I am in **Case 2** so when I call `PreferenceActivity.finish()`, the child screen is closed, parent also and I am directly navigated to my `MainActivity`. :)

Answer (score 0):

> You may finish ParentActivity then start Child Activity, now then you
>   finish your child you will go back to main activity

Or

You can use in manifest meta-data

```
 <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.in.class" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you gave me a good direction to think for!